# What is the relationship between Death of the Endless and Daniel Hall like?

Tags: neil-gaiman, the-sandman

Reading the "Sandman" series you can clearly see that Death and Dream were close  - in *The Sadman presents: the Thessaliad* someone even says to Thessaly about her relationship with Morpheus that

> You never stood a chance with him , because of his unhealthy attraction to his own sister. <sup>*</sup>

In any case, we can definitely see that Death was very upset when she had to take Dream - in the "World's end" she is walking last in the procession looking very sad.

And then comes the Daniel Hall, who is the new Dream of the Endless - is there anywhere (**not only in the "Sandman"** - Daniel and Death appeared in other works as well) described how does her relationship with this "new brother" look like? Knowing Death, she will be quite friendly (she is like that to EVERYONE), but is there anything showing that she either genuinely likes Damian or that she is upset by him "pretending to be her brother"?

<sup>* Although it was rather supposed to mean that Morpheus was looking for a way to die</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I'd say the asterix is the correct way to interpret that.  Good question, but with Daniel making only brief cameos outside *The Wake*, I don't know how well it can be answered

Comment: @Radhil I'm happy for answers from other sources - I know that Daniel shown up in other sources (i.e. in [JL8](http://limbero.org/jl8/79) ). I'm just wondering is there somewhere at least description of Death and Daniel meeting together.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the nature of the Endless. Daniel Hall **is** Dream, to same extent his predecessor as. Daniel possesses all attributes (and memories) of previous Dream. Plus, Morpheus himself compares aspects of the Endless to the faucets of the Emerald: we may see different faucets, but it's the same stone. Provided that Death can *see* the real face of things, I see no reason whatsoever for her to treat Daniel differently, nevermind dislike him for "pretending" to be Dream. Nobody dislikes Despair, for some reason.

Comment: Daniel has completely different personality than Morpheus: he is kind, he is not above asking for help in contrary to often arrogant Morpheus. Also he is still Daniel: he remembers and loves his mother.  So he is a Dream, but a different Dream,  same as its a different Despair. And he is anxious about meeting his new siblings, hence my question.

Answer (score 4):

That's a really good question and something I would really like to know and see in future works. I agree with Radhil that there is probably not enough info to answer it but since your question got me revisiting my Sandman collection I will try to give you a (highly speculative) answer anyway.

There is one face to face interaction that I could find:

- After becoming Dream in the family meeting

[image]

Now this interaction lack dialogue, but nonetheless we can read something about facial expressions. I perceive a compassionate look, mixed with sadness.

I think kindness it's in the very nature of Death. It's not within her to hold a grudge and hate Daniel but to show him warmth and help. Yet I believe she, like Despair, will remember Morpheus forever, evidenced in how Death went to visit Morpheus mortal friend after the Wake.

Comment: I daresay it will be the same relationship as between Despair and Desire or Dream and Despair. It is not the first time one of the Endless was killed and replaced, Despair was the first.